# how to do on the Angular svg map region select area?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I added this  map for the angular type script project, dose any one know to how to create select region on the map

**[stack blitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ea5uwb?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

**[here the jsFiddle code link](https://jsfiddle.net/phwar4vd/)**

**css here**

```
p {font-size: 12px}

#core {
  fill: #ff4f81;
  animation: pulse1 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

#radar  {
  fill: #F99EAD;
  animation: pulse2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(2);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(6, 6);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.row-wrap {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.row-middle {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #0E76FE;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.row-middle-two{
  font-size: 17px;color: #808490;
}
.row-middle-three{
  font-size: 14px;color: #9DA2AE;
}
.row-bottom-small{
  font-size: 10px; color: #B9C0CD;
}.row-top-small{
   font-size: 10px;
  color: #B9C0CD;
 }
.row-bottom{
  color: #A3A9B5;font-size: 12px;
}
.row-top{
color: #A3A9B5;font-size: 12px;
}
p {font-size: 12px}



#core {
  fill: #ff4f81;
  animation: pulse1 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

#radar  {
  fill: #F99EAD;
  animation: pulse2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(2);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(6, 6);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.row-wrap {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.row-middle {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #0E76FE;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.row-middle-two{
  font-size: 17px;color: #808490;
}
.row-middle-three{
  font-size: 14px;color: #9DA2AE;
}
.row-bottom-small{
  font-size: 10px; color: #B9C0CD;
}.row-top-small{
   font-size: 10px;
  color: #B9C0CD;
 }
.row-bottom{
  color: #A3A9B5;font-size: 12px;
}
.row-top{
color: #A3A9B5;font-size: 12px;
}
p {font-size: 12px}



#core {
  fill: #ff4f81;
  animation: pulse1 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}
#radar  {
  fill: #F99EAD;
  animation: pulse2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes pulse1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(2);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(6, 6);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.row-wrap {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.row-middle {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #0E76FE;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.row-middle-two{
  font-size: 17px;color: #808490;
}
.row-middle-three{
  font-size: 14px;color: #9DA2AE;
}
.row-bottom-small{
  font-size: 10px; color: #B9C0CD;
}.row-top-small{
   font-size: 10px;
  color: #B9C0CD;
 }
.row-bottom{
  color: #A3A9B5;font-size: 12px;
}
.row-top{
color: #A3A9B5;font-size: 12px;
}
p {font-size: 12px}



#core {
  fill: #ff4f81;
  animation: pulse1 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

#radar  {
  fill: #F99EAD;
  animation: pulse2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes pulse1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(2);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(6, 6);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Adding it to angular | *edit*

To use it inside angular, you should use its (angular's) [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), and specifically, for your case, I would use `ngAfterViewInit` in your `appComponent`. There should be some altercations from the code I wrote earlier since *typescript does not support style property on elements*.

[this is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jsytgd?file=src/app/app.component.ts), and below is the relevant code

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let selectedArea = null;
    let areas = document.querySelectorAll<SVGElement>('path'); // gets an array of all of the paths in the DOM
    areas.forEach((area) => {. // for each svg path
      area.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        area.style.fill = 'red'; // add red on hover
      });
      area.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        area.style.fill = '';  // return to default on mouse out
      });
      area.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log(selectedArea);
        if (selectedArea) {
          // check if there is a selectedArea
          document.querySelector<SVGElement>(`#${selectedArea}`).setAttribute('class', 'st0') // changed
        }
        if (selectedArea !== area.id) {
          selectedArea = area.id;
          area.setAttribute('class', 'selectedArea'); // changed
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

---

It depends on what you want to achieve. if you want to highlight a region on hover, add this to your CSS:

```
path:hover { fill: red; }
```

If you want a more customisable method that allows you to store your user's choice, you can use JS.
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/dq9gny87/1/) is a minimal version (stores the choice in a variable).
I added to your CSS a class named `selectedArea`. And using JS, I chose all your SVG paths and assigned `eventListeneres` to them.

i cant attach your whole code because your HTML is to long, so the CSS will be as follows:

```
#core {
  fill: #ff4f81;
  animation: pulse1 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

#radar {
  fill: #F99EAD;
  animation: pulse2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(2);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(6, 6);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


.selectedArea {
  stroke: black;
  fill: purple;
}
```

JS:

```
let selectedArea = null
let areas = document.querySelectorAll("path")
areas.forEach((area) => {
  area.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    area.style.fill = "red"
  });
  area.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    area.style.fill = ""
  });
  area.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(selectedArea)
    if (selectedArea) { // check if there is a selectedArea
      document.querySelector(`#${selectedArea}`).classList = "st0"
    }
    if (selectedArea !== area.id) {
      selectedArea = area.id
      area.classList = "selectedArea"
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: not working on the angular type script

Comment: can you post your angular code? i made it based on your fiddle

Comment: here the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ea5uwb?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: tnx, I solved it and added it to my answer. let me know if it helped :)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your time, are you sure this  is this  example working correctly ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jsytgd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: oh man, i forgot to save it. i'll edit the link

Comment: HI, Thanks for your valuable time and answer :)